# Denied file read access on file I own and have full r/w permissions on

Tags: macos, permission

I received an email with a plain text attachment (named 'noname') via Gmail and downloaded it using Chrome from gmail.com. It's a recurring automated report. Everyday I get the file , download it, open it, read it, and enjoy my life. Some days like today I get the file, download it and TextEdit on OS X won't let me open it.

TextEdit reports "The document "noname.txt" could not be opened. You don't have permissions."

A **Get Info** in Finder shows permissions:

> ram (Me) Read & Write
>   Staff Read only
>   Everyone Read only

From a terminal I can do whatever I want to it (read, write, rename...). An `ls -l` shows:
  -rw-r--r--@   1 ram  staff

An `ls -le` shows the same (i.e, no ACLs shown).

What gives?

Comment: Three unrelated questions: Have you considered hard-disk failure? Have you tried opening it with vi in a Terminal? Are there extended attributes on the downloaded file (quarantine or so)?

Comment: Sorry didn't see the "@". What are the extended attributes on the file, then?

Comment: The file is a plain text file created by running a script script that outputs plain-text and piping it into `mail`

Comment: com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms  316Bcom.apple.quarantine   71B

Comment: Disk Utility doesn't report any problems. Everything from the terminal, vi included, works without a hitch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From debugging a different problem (which showed up as `deny file-read-data` in the Console, see the other answer), it seems that sandboxd prevents sandboxed applications from reading quarantined data, so **I think** you'd need to remove the attribute with:

`xattr -d com.apple.quarantine /path/to/file`

(see for instance https://superuser.com/a/28394/46794). You'd need to prefix the command with `sudo` if the file didn't belong to your user, but according to your info it does.

The other user reported that using a non-sandboxed application fixed the problem, and this would confirm that sandboxing is at fault.

An aside: When `ls` reports extended attributes with @ next to the permission field, you don't need `ls -le file`, but instead `ls -l@ file`.

Comment: Thanks for the ls -l@ catch. I totally got that wrong and as a result didn't see the attributes that clarified and confirmed answers suggesting quarantine. All the affected files have, since some update (from Apple?), been tagged with  com.apple.quarantine.

Comment: IIUC, applications downloading from the Internet are encouraged to tag the downloaded files as quarantined, so that the user is warned when he/she opens them by double-clicking. The mechanism is apparently in place since OS X 10.5, so maybe Chrome was updated to use it. One API to do that is described here:
http://ilostmynotes.blogspot.de/2012/06/gatekeeper-xprotect-and-quarantine.html, which points to https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/LaunchServicesKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009250-SW10 for some official docs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the same problem I had, but every now and then TextEdit (and not any other application) started showing a dialog like this when I tried to open any file:

> **The document “test.txt” could not be opened. You don’t have permission.**
>
> To view or change permissions, select the item in the Finder and choose File > Get Info.

There were messages like this in `system.log`:

```
9/13/12 10:41:42.952 PM sandboxd[21081]: ([357]) TextEdit(357) deny file-read-data /Users/lauri/Desktop/test.txt
9/13/12 10:41:55.118 PM TextEdit[357]: NSFileVersion tried to tried to add a new generation and failed. Versioned file URL: file://localhost/Users/lauri/Notes/test.txt, contents URL: file://localhost/Users/lauri/Notes/test.txt.sb-de6477ff-BhVNrq, error: Error Domain=GSLibraryErrorDomain Code=1 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (GSLibraryErrorDomain error 1.)"
9/13/12 10:41:55.118 PM TextEdit[357]: NSDocument failed to preserve the old version of a document. Here's the error:
Error Domain=GSLibraryErrorDomain Code=1 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (GSLibraryErrorDomain error 1.)"
9/13/12 10:41:55.119 PM TextEdit[357]: <Document: 0x7f971d00a510>: An error occurred while attempting to preserve the backup file at file://localhost/Users/lauri/Notes/test.txt.sb-de6477ff-BhVNrq: Error Domain=GSLibraryErrorDomain Code=1 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (GSLibraryErrorDomain error 1.)"
```

I was able to open files normally after quitting and reopening TextEdit.

I haven't seen those dialogs after I replaced TextEdit with [TextEditPlus](https://github.com/jjgod/TextEditPlus), which is basically a non-sandboxed fork of TextEdit.

Answer (score -2):

Quit, don't just close, but Quit TextEdit. When TextEdit starts again it will "remember" who you are.

When Text Edit has the Main Menu
Cmd-Q 
or
Main Menu / TextEdit / Quit
or
Right Click on the TaskEdit dock icon and choose Quit.