# Why is SpotlightNetHelp denied file-read-data for root?

Tags: macos, spotlight, permission, error

I'm getting many of these two similar errors on my console.

> 10/21/15 11:06:29.737 AM sandboxd[140]: ([368]) SpotlightNetHelp(368) deny file-read-data /
>     10/21/15 11:07:11.000 AM kernel[0]: Sandbox: SpotlightNetHelp(368) deny(1) file-read-data /

I've check the extended attributes of `/` to see if [it's quarantined](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/105155/denied-file-read-access-on-file-i-own-and-have-full-r-w-permissions-on), but there are none:

```
$ xattr / 
[nothing]
```

Root `/` is owned by `root` and in group `wheel` with permissions `drwxr-xr-x`. For what it's worth, other Spotlight errors include many

> 10/21/15 10:53:49.623 AM SpotlightNetHelper[368]: tcp_connection_tls_session_error_callback_imp 276 __tcp_connection_tls_session_callback_write_block_invoke.434 error 22

where `276` so far varies up to 293. What could be causing these deny file-read-data errors, and what can I do about it?

Comment: Are you on El Capitan / Did you enable SIP ?

Comment: I am on El Capitan, but I had these errors *before* upgrading. I haven't taken any action to enable SIP (this is the first I've heard of it).

Comment: Apple has enabled a new default security oriented featured called System Integrity Protection, often called rootless, in OS X 10.11 onward. The rootless feature is aimed at preventing Mac OS X compromise by malicious code, whether intentionally or accidentally, and essentially what SIP does is lock down specific system level locations in the file system while simultaneously preventing certain processes from attaching to system-level processes. http://osxdaily.com/2015/10/05/disable-rootless-system-integrity-protection-mac-os-x/

Comment: Tons of these lines are placed in my logs along before SIP & El Capitan